# I need to make jqvmap disappear on mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, jqvmap

This is my site in progress http://www.wearemovingto.com I am using a template as an example but I want the map to disappear on mobile view and have a dropdown list take its place, just wondering what code to use? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be inclined to use the CSS3 media queries.  If you add a select with the ID `vmapSelect`:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #vmapSelect {display:none;}
  @media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #vmap {display:none;}
    #vmapSelect {display:block;}
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I now need a dropdown list to appear on responsive view

It has to only appear on mobile devices (phone/tablet, etc) 
and not appear on desktop/laptop/mac 


The drop down list/menu has 3 sections 
First section 
Continent (Africa, Europe, America etc) I select Asia and the next list/menu loads 
Second section 
Region (Sth East Asia, North Asia etc) I select South East Asia and the next list/menu loads 
Third section 
Country (Indonesia, Vietnam, Thailand,  etc) I select Thailand and it takes me to Thailand.html 

Thanks

Comment: In that case, make the `vmapSelect` be a div containing the dropdowns.  Here's an article on how to make consecutive dropdowns: http://coursesweb.net/javascript/multiple-select-dropdown-list-javascript_t  Let me know how it goes, and if necessary post another question.

Comment: It worked perfect, sorry the site wouldn't let me post another Q.